# findOneAndUpdate for a 2dsphere

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, socket.io, geolocation

```
const sessionId = uuid.v4();
//Session.
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("locationData", async (data) => {
    const latitude = data.latitude;
    const longitude = data.longitude;
    Session.findOneAndUpdate(
      { sessionId: sessionId },
      {
        $set: {
          location: { coordinates: [longitude, latitude] },
          speed: data.speed,
        },
      },
      { upsert: true, new: true },
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log("Data inserted/updated");
      }
    );
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

im trying to get realtime location data with socket io and put it in my DB, it was working perfect till i realised i need to add index:"2dsphere" to the coords, apparently the  findOneAndUpdate doesnt work with a geospatial point. what should i use in this case please

```
const sessionId = uuid.v4();
//Session.
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("locationData", async (data) => {
    const latitude = data.latitude;
    const longitude = data.longitude;
    Session.findOneAndUpdate(
      { sessionId: sessionId },
      {
        $set: {
          location: { coordinates: [longitude, latitude] },
          speed: data.speed,
        },
      },
      { upsert: true, new: true },
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log("Data inserted/updated");
      }
    );
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked by modifying my code:

```
location: {
  type: "Point",
  coordinates: [longitude, latitude],
},
```